# Webmatrix session_destroy()

Tags: php, session-variables, webmatrix

I have written a simple code for $_SESSION variable in the first php file:

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["name"] = "John";
 ?>
```

and in another php file to render this:

```
  <?php
      session_start();          
      echo $_SESSION["name"];
   ?>
```

But after that i used `session_unset()`; and `session_destroy()`; and after that i can't render any new `$_SESSION` variable nor the existing one. I am using Microsoft WebMatrix program and Chrome as main browser. Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That is because session_destroy(); destroys the current session and also sends a header to the browser to delete the session variable. In the same time the session is deleted on the server (in PHP) and the $_SESSION variables can no longer be used. You can always try to save the $_SESSION in another variable;

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = 'foo';
```

Next page:

```
session_start();
$saveSession = $_SESSION;
session_destroy();
var_dump($_SESSION); //Gives an empty array
var_dump($saveSession); //Still has ['test' => 'foo']
```

More information: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php and http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Also, sidenote, you do not need to open and close PHP tags if they are combined;

```
  <?php
  session_start();
  echo $_SESSION["name"];
  ?>
```

works just as well as

```
  <?php
  session_start();
  ?>
  <?php
  echo $_SESSION["name"];
  ?>
```

Comment: I am still having problems, i even tried and copied your code and it still doesn't work. Does it have something to do with cookies?

Comment: It can, the PHP session is usally sent as a cookie to the user - PHPSESSID contains a hash of the PHP session's identifier for that specific user.